# Map forms field with the url parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery is it possible to map forms field with the url parameters?

e.g i have url :

```
www.example.com/search?city=mumbai&countyr=IN
```

whenever this URL is browse it should set the form field's `city` , `country` value with `mumbai` and `IN` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the parameters from the URL this way:

```
$.urlParam = function(name) {
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results == null) return null;
    else return results[1] || 0;    
} 

var city = $.urlParam('city');
```

Then set the value of your input:

```
$("#city").val(city);
```

Answer (score 0):

For GET parameters, you can grab them from `document.location.search`:

```
function getQueryParams(qs) {
    qs = qs.split("+").join(" ");
    var params = {},
        tokens,
        re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

    while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
        params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])]
            = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
    }

    return params;
}

var $_GET = getQueryParams(document.location.search);
```

After that, just retrieve your correct GET, and set the value of your input ;)